# JMeter BeanShell Property Setting Across Thread Group

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I'm trying to calculate the time between two events in JMeter using BeanShell PostProcessors.

In the first block, I get the time and store it as a property. This is in one Thread Group.
Then in another Thread Group, I have the second BeanShell block. I get an error which I cannot figure out. I have pasted the error here. Thank you very much for your hints and advice!

Here are the two pieces of BeanShell code:

FIRST POSTPROCESSOR:

```
//Set the current time to the time_upload variable
long time_upload = prev.getTime(); // get POST Time

props.put("time_upload",(String.valueof(time_upload))); 
log.info("Time for Upload is: " + time_upload); // print difference to jmeter.log file
```

SECOND POSTPROCESSOR:

```
String no_saved_carts = vars.get("no_saved_carts");
String no_saved_carts_trimmed = no_saved_carts.trim();

String temp_description = vars.get("description");
String temp_description_no_space = temp_description.trim();

String time_upload_local = props.get("time_upload");


if(temp_description_no_space.equals("</") || no_saved_carts_trimmed.equals("No Saved Carts Found")){
    vars.put("description","true");
} else{
    vars.put("description","false");
    //set the time to time_processing based on time_upload
    long time_processing_done = prev.getTime(); // get time 
    long time_upload_long = Long.parseLong(time_upload_local); // get HTTP Sampler 1 execution time from variable
    long delta = (time_processing_done - time_upload); // calculate difference
    log.info("Time difference is: " + delta + " ms"); // print difference to jmeter.log file
}
```

The relevant part of the ERROR LOG:

```
2016/06/03 17:21:22 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``//Set the current time to the time_upload variable long time_upload = prev.getTi . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Static method valueof( long ) not found in class'java.lang.String' 
2016/06/03 17:21:22 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``//Set the current time to the time_upload variable long time_upload = prev.getTi . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Static method valueof( long ) not found in class'java.lang.String' 
2016/06/03 17:21:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Upload Saved Cart Thread Group 1-1 
2016/06/03 17:21:22 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Upload Saved Cart Thread Group 1-1 
2016/06/03 17:21:22 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String temp_description = vars.get("description"); String no_saved_carts = vars. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Long.parseLong 
2016/06/03 17:21:22 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String temp_description = vars.get("description"); String no_saved_carts = vars. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Long.parseLong 
2016/06/03 17:21:26 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Check Upload Status 2-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert long to String using String.valueOf() method, there are following options:

1. If you still want String just change the line to convert long to String to look like:

   ```
   props.put("time_upload", Objects.toString(time_upload,null));
   ```
2. Get rid of long -> String and vice versa conversion, `props` is an usual [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class instance so it stores [Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

   In first PostProcessor:

   ```
   long time_upload = prev.getTime();
   props.put("time_upload", time_upload);
   ```

   In second PostProcessor:

   ```
   long time_upload_long = props.get("time_upload"); // no need to cast from String
   ```
3. You can use [bsh.shared namespace](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) to keep any Object - it will be accessible by all Thread Groups

   In first PostProcessor:

   ```
   bsh.shared.time_upload = prev.getTime();
   ```

   In second PostProcessor:

   ```
   long time_upload = bsh.shared.time_upload
   ```

---

You can get more informative error messages in *jmeter.log* file in case of Beanshell script error by surrounding your code with try/catch block like:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Something wrong", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more JMeter and Beanshell tips and tricks.

Comment: excellent answer! Thank you for helping me, and teaching me more about JMeter :)